# display large text in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have string array of quotes and want to display in libgdx. I am doing as follows

```
public int quoteIndexNo =2; 

public String[] quotes = {
        "Sometimes the heart sees what is " +
        "invisible to the eye. H. Jackson " +
        "Brown, Jr.",           
        "Being deeply loved by someone gives" +
        " you strength, while loving someone " +
        "deeply gives you courage. Lao Tzu",};  

                    font.draw(batch, quotes[quoteIndexNo], 50, 100);
```

but problem is, being text large it is not properly showing in screen.
how can I make sure that only 15 characters are visible in single line and rest part of string in another line.

Comment: so it will appear as "Sometimes the h\neart sees that is" - line broken in the middle of a word?

Comment: yes exactly @Axarydax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use drawMultiLine . In your case use it like this
font.drawMultiLine(batch, lovequotes[quoteIndexNo], 50 ,150 ); 
may be this will help u